# set dynamic meta tags in reactjs when js is disabled

Tags: reactjs, tags

I'm getting some problems with google crawlers and meta tags, I'm using reactjs with react-helmet (no ssr).
React-helmet does work but google search does not seem to find the tags I added. I know that crawlers do run the website without js enabled, when testing this I can see that react-helmet does not render the tags when js is disabled (works fine when it is enabled).

The fact that react-helmet does not render tags when js is disabled might be the reason why the description and titles are wrong in google search. maybe that finding a way to renders the proper tags when js is disabled might fix the problem.

Any idea on how to do that?

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options if you want to make your React pages discoverable on search engines: server-side rendering (SSR) or prerendering.

**Server Side Rendering:**

React can render pages on the server-side, making it easier for search engine crawlers to discover and index your content. However, it requires a more advanced setup using a library like [Next.JS](https://nextjs.org/) along with additional time-consuming and expensive server.

**Prerendering**

Meanwhile, using [Prerender](https://prerender.io/) is painless and straightforward. Their software will seamlessly create fully-rendered, static HTML versions of your website for social media, search engine crawlers and more.
However, you have to install the Prerender.io middleware on your server.

Comment: Hi, since I wrote this question I started using NextJS which is like you pointed out the right solution